# doubletap on button with callback to segue causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, callback, uibutton, segue

I have a button with this:

```
- (IBAction)themeBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *language = [[OnlineStore sharedStore]getTheLanguage];
        [[OnlineStore sharedStore]getTheThemeBaseGuides:language callback:^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"from main to themecategory" sender:self];
    }]
}
```

But when user happens to doubletap the button it causes a crash. Probably because next viewcontroller is being loaded twice onto the heap (my guess) and the error message I get when I try to return with `UINavigationController` pop from that second `UIViewController`is: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MySecondViewController: 0xb257b80>.`

How can I do to prevent this?

I have tried to put it inside callback within:

```
    if ([NSStringFromClass([[viewControlles lastObject] class]) isEqualToString: @"MainViewController"]) {
```

and I have tried to do the callback within the selector goToNextView in the btn

```
   [self performSelector:@selector(goToNextView)  withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
```

No luck.
Any suggestions. And please ask if this is unclear since I am a bit tired and just about to try to sleep now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore user interaction until the view controller disappears:

```
- (IBAction)themeBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *language = [[OnlineStore sharedStore]getTheLanguage];
    [[OnlineStore sharedStore]getTheThemeBaseGuides:language callback:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"from main to themecategory" sender:self];
    }]
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
```

Or just disable user interaction on the button in a similar manner:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
...
button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank u Timothy! I really needed this answer.